# Resource was blocked due a MIME type mismatch (text/html) (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm developing an AJAX HTTP-POST request to an API, but I always get the following error on Mozilla Firefox:

> Resource “https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmqG55tt2d2FcT_WQ3WjCSKmtyFpkOcdprSITn45-4UgVJnzp9/exec?url=http://librairy.linkeddata.es/ods-model/classes&callback=jQuery31109831060291564537_1560774264336&text=aaaaaaaaaaaa&_=1560774264337” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (“text/html”) (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

```
$(document).on('submit', '#sendtext_form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var text1 = $('#textForm').val();
  var text = text1.replace(/["']/g, "\\'");

  $.ajax({
    url:'http://librairy.linkeddata.es/ods-model/classes',
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {
      "text": text,
    },
    success: function(result_api) {
      console.log(result_api);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Visit the URL. Read the page. It's showing an error message (because it's been called too many times in one day).